# download cover art from musicbrainz with java

Tags: java, albumart, musicbrainz

I am struggling for a couple of hours now on how to link a discid to a musicbrainz mbid.

So, using dietmar-steiner / JMBDiscId

```
JMBDiscId discId = new JMBDiscId();

if (discId.init(PropertyFinder.getProperty("libdiscid.path")))
{
    String musicBrainzDiscID = discId.getDiscId(PropertyFinder.getProperty("cdrom.path"));
}
```

or  musicbrainzws2-java

```
Disc controller = new Disc();
String drive = PropertyFinder.getProperty("cdrom.path"); 

try {
    DiscWs2 disc =controller.lookUp(drive);
    log.info("DISC: " + disc.getDiscId() + " match: " + disc.getReleases().size() + " releases");
....
```

I can extract a discid for freedb or musicbrainz easily (more or less), but I have not found a way on calculating the id I that I need to download cover art via the CoverArtArchiveClient from last.fm.

```
CoverArtArchiveClient client = new DefaultCoverArtArchiveClient();

try
{
  UUID mbid = UUID.fromString("mbid to locate release");
  fm.last.musicbrainz.coverart.CoverArt coverArt = client.getByMbid(mbid);
```

Theoretically, I assume, I could you the data collected by musicbrainzws2-java to trigger a search, and then use the mbid from the result ... but that cannot be the best option to do.

I am happy about any push into the right direction...

Cheers,
Ed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't calculate the MBID. The MBID is attached on every entity you retrieve from MusicBrainz.
When getting releases by DiscID you get a list. Each entry is a release and has an MBID, accessible with `getId()`:

```
for (ReleaseWs2 rel : disc.getReleases()){
   log.info("MBID: " + rel.getId() + ", String: " + rel.toString());
}
```

You then probably want to try the CoverArtArchive (CAA) for every release and take the first cover art you get.

Unfortunately I don't know of any API documentation for musicbrainzws2 on the web. I recommend running `javadoc` on all source files.